# What android permission cause "read sensitive log data" permission label in Google Play?

Tags: android, security, permissions, privacy

After app building and merging of manifest my app manifest request the following permissions (`app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/arm/release/AndroidManifest.xml`):

```
<!-- sd card -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- downloads -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- ga -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- in-app billing -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

However in Google Play it looks like it's able to "read sensitive log data". How can that be?

Previous versions of the app requested "read_log" permissions to provide more information for app crashes and it's secure as the app is unable to read log output of another apps. Are previous versions permissions shown too?

Comment: it's probably the billing one, i've not seen that verbage, and i've used all the others perms

Comment: it could be but there is no "read_log" permission in the final manifest. If it was the reason i expect to see it in final manifest and be able to see in `build/output/logs/manifest-merger-arm-release-report.txt` where it came from

Comment: well, you can try building without and see if it goes away...